# Vue.Js | Components isn't working. | Unknown custom element: <image-upload>

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have this error :

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<image-upload>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

**In myApp.js i added :**

```
Vue.component('image-upload',require('./components/ImageUpload.vue').default);
```

In **ImageUpload.Vue** i have this code:

```
<script>
    import Croppie from 'croppie'

    export default {
        props: ['imgUrl'],
        mounted() {
            this.image = this.imgUrl
            this.setupCroppie()
        },
        data() {
            return {
                croppie: null,
                image: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setUpCroppie() {
                let el = document.getElementById('croppie')
                this.croppie = new Croppie(el, {
                    viewport: {width: 200, height: 200, type: 'circle'},
                    boundary: {width: 220, height: 220},
                    showZoomer: true,
                    enableOrientation: true
                })
                this.croppie.bind({
                    url: this.image
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
<template>
    <div class="image-upload-wrapper image-upload">
        <p>this is my component</p>
        <div id="croppie"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In blade:

```
<image-upload img-url="{{url('img/user.png')}}"></image-upload>
```

I'm following the doc here to use CroppieJs 
https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

Thanks..

Comment: What version of Laravel mix are you using? Have you recompiled your js since adding this component e.g. `npm run dev` / `yarn dev`?

Comment: Thx sir for ur interest. I did yes, i have no errors in App.js . But note please i use another vuejs script in the same blade. ( For other functions and it's working fine)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a : to your vue component.

`<image-upload :img-url="{{url('img/user.png')}}"></image-upload>`

Does the Vue component appear in the Vue.js inspecter?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Comment: When i add : i have Error compiling.. , in my Vue.js inspect i a have a component, but i think it's relative to a existing vuejs file i have in the same blade.

Comment: I've never used the `.default` at the end of my route.